# How to plot a windrose as a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, windrose

my wind rose diagram going out of the subplot

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
fig=plt.figure()
plot1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 6), (0, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
plot2 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 6), (2, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
plot3 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 6), (0, 2), rowspan=4, colspan=4)

plot1.plot([1,2,3,4],[3,2,5,6])
plot2.scatter([1,3,5,7],[2,7,3,1])
rect = [1, 1, 2, 2]
wa = WindroseAxes(fig, rect)
fig.add_axes(wa)
wa.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
```

[final result is this. but i need all three graphs in single figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOlpN.png)

I am trying to plot all the 3 graphs in a single figure but I got my wind rose graph out of the figure

Comment: It's showing error. (__init__() missing 2 required arguments: 'fig' and 'rect')

Comment: I would like to keep the figure as plot3. Any rect I pass. It only plots it separately and overlaps the existing plot.

Comment: wa = WindroseAxes.from_ax(ax=plot3). It is showing as a barplot. But I want a polar axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [example from github](https://github.com/scls19fr/windrose/blob/master/samples/example_subplots.py), in `plt.subplot2grid()` and similar functions, you need to set `projection='windrose'`. You should remove `wa = WindroseAxes(fig, rect)` and `fig.add_axes(wa)`. At the end of the code `plt.tight_layout()` seems to work, it moves the subplots a bit to avoid overlapping labels.

Here is the updated example (also renaming `plot1` to `ax1`, to be more consistent with the matplotlib documentation).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import windrose
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 6), (0, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 6), (2, 0), rowspan=2, colspan=2)
wa = plt.subplot2grid((4, 6), (0, 2), rowspan=4, colspan=4, projection='windrose')

ax1.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 5, 6])
ax2.scatter([1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 7, 3, 1])
ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360
wa.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: windrose axes inside a subplot]